# Buckingham Pi Theorem doesnt work for this case?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

Question from my Fluid Dynamics book (White 7e - 5.15)

The thrust F of a propeller is generally thought to be a function of its diameter D and angular velocity Ω, the forward speed V, and the density ρ and visocity μ of the fluid. Rewrite this relationship as a dimensionless function.

I want to solve this question using the Buckingham Pi Theorem. The solutions provided by my professor only use the Ipsen's method.

But I don't understand what repeating variables to choose.

According to the Buckingham Pi theorem each pi must contain the repeating variables. But in this example that is not possible??